# Cluj-Napoca Sitecore Meetup: Sitecore Community meetup #5, November 22, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Tuesday, 22 November 2018 at 18:00pm
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Tuesday, 22 November 2018 at 16:00pm
- **Location:** ThatDevSpace, str. Brasov, nr.37 · Cluj-Napoca, Cluj-Napoca, Romania
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/events/255741058/)
- **Contact:** [Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/)
- **Agenda:**

  - What's new in Sitecore 9.1 - Sebastian Tecsi, Sitecore MVP 2018
  - Sitecore xConnect & Marketing Automation - Dani Mocan, Sitecore MVP 2017, 2018
  - Tips and Tricks in Commerce 9 - Vlad Iobagiu, Ex Sitecorean(2016-2018), Ex Sitecore MVP(2014,2015,2016)